# AWS Lambda Function Duration Constantly Increasing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a fairly complex AWS Lambda function which loads data from an S3 bucket, loads a trained Keras model from the same bucket, uses the model to perform a prediction and sends this prediction back to another Lambda function. This is scheduled to run every minute.

I noticed noticed a steady increase in the duration of the function until my 10 second time-out threshold is hit. The functions then starts again the next minute, with execution back down at around 2 seconds duration, and gradually increasing each time until it hits the time-out again.

I can't understand exactly what is causing this (it doesn't happen to any of my other functions, including those which also read/write to S3) so I'm at a loss - and would really like to fix it if possible. I have updated the question to include a simplified version of the code, which is shown below:

```
import json
import os
import boto3
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import keras

from keras.models import Model, load_model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.activations import sigmoid
from keras import initializers
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

"""
   .... functions for defining my ML model, loading & preparing data, 
        train/test split and prediction
"""


def handler(event, context):

    """
    Returns a dict of expected returns per instrument
    """

    ## Initialise the connection to S3
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    ## Download the latest trained model from s3
    s3.Object('data', 'Model.h5').download_file('/tmp/model.h5') 

    ## Download latest data from s3
    s3.Object('data', 'prices.csv').download_file('/tmp/prices.csv')
    s3_data = pd.read_csv('/tmp/prices.csv',index_col='time')


    ## Load Data
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = load_data(filename='/tmp/prices.csv', Ys=instruments, test_size=1)
    latest_data = X_test.tail(1)  # Get most recent record

    ## Load model into Keras
    model = load_model('/tmp/model.h5')

    ## Model Prediction
    ys = predict_from_data(latest_data, model)

    ## Convert expected returns to dict
    forecasts = pd.DataFrame( dict( {y:ys[:,i] for i,y in enumerate(instruments)}) ) 

    return forecasts.to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

What could be the cause, and what might the solution be to prevent this behaviour? Can I prevent container-reuse, and force a cold start each time (and if possible, would that really be the best way to optimise the performance?)

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell without having code snippets to look at. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: At a very high level, if you are keeping lots of objects in memory and if the container where Lambda runs is reused, you may see same results as you would normally do running it on permanent infrastructure. You still need to write efficient code for Lambda functions.

Comment: @alex067:I can try to provide some code snippets but for the sake of clarity I don't receive any errors, except the time-out error when execution gradually increases to hit the 10s user-defined duration limit.

Comment: @Asdfg: I'm afraid I don't understand your point; what remains in memory after a Python script is completed executing?

Comment: A lot. Lambda containers maintain global variables in memory, so unless the container dies and/or a new one spawns, there's a high chance that you're adding to and existing value which slows down your application. For this we would need to see the code to be certain.

Comment: To understand container reuse, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for the link; it seems related but I'm not sure what to do about it (the link suggests re-use is efficient due to preventing cold-starts.. but in my case the cold starts are a lot quicker!). It could be due to the .csv or the .h5 file being downloaded to /tmp again and again... but the .csv is orders of magnitude larger than the .h5, and I have another function which downloads the same .csv but doesn't show the same problem! I've updated the question with code showing the logic, in the hopes someone can point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Hey @Zac, did you find the root cause for steady increase in the average duration?
Even I'm facing this issue. I'd like to know about your findings